# Difference between Int... and Int[]

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Why does the following fail to compile (getting this for an error: Could not find an overload for '_conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments) when passing in a Int...?

```
func sumOfNumbers(numbers: Int...) -> Int{
    var sum = 0;
    for number in numbers{
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}

func averageOfInts(numbers: Int...) -> Int{
    var sumNums: Int = 0
    sumNums = sumOfNumbers(numbers)
    var count = numbers.count
    return sumOfNumbers(numbers)/numbers.count
}
```

But when a Int[] is used in place of the Int... it compiles and works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the type of an argument is `Int...` all the subsequent args are bunched into the array for you, whereas `Int[]` requires you to pass **just one** argument, an array of Ints:

```
func sumOfIntsSplat(numbers:Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0;
    for number in numbers{
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}
func sumOfIntsArray(numbers: Int[]) -> Int{
    var sum = 0;
    for number in numbers{
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}
```

#### Usage

```
sumOfIntsSplat(1,2,3,4,5)
sumOfIntsArray([1,2,3,4,5])
```

The `Int...` syntax is referred to as a [Variadic parameter in the swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_213)

(aside: I borrowed the name "splat" from coffeescript, where I first encountered this syntax)

Comment: The real problem here is that `Int[]` and `Int...` are not convertible to each other (yet) and there is currently no way to pass an array to a variadic parameter.

Comment: @Sulthan I completely agree

Answer (score 0):

`Int...` means one or more parameters of type `Int`.

Like sum(3,4,5,6)

While `Int[]` means a single parameter which contains Ints. (Like an array)

Like sum([3,4,5,6])